# Converting Table data to the xml structured data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I stuck the below requirement, Here I have to show all the table data to the xml structured data, I tried with the following, I'm getting xml structure but struggling to show row data with table headers like below

```
<rowset>
<row name='SequnceNumber'>
    <row>Item</row> 
    <row>Weight</row>   
    <row>LableNo</row>
    <row>Unitcost</row>
    <row>Delete</row>
</rowset>
<rowset>
<rowset name='1212121'>
    <Item>test1</Item>
    <Weight>3000</Weight>   
    <LableNo>test1</LableNo>    
    <Unitcost>test1</Unitcost>  
    <Delete>test1</Delete>
</rowset>
```

I tried with below code,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#idXmlData").click(function(){
        var xmlStart =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">";
        var xml = xmlStart;
        $(".mutliple tr").each(function() {
        var cells = $("td", this);
        if (cells.length > 0) {
            xml +="<rowset name='" + cells.eq(0).text() + "'>\n";
            for (var i = 1; i < cells.length; ++i) {
                //var tableHeaders=["SequnceNumber","Item","Weight","LableNo","Unitcost","Delete"];
                //for(var j=0;j<tableHeaders.length;j++){
                    // xml += "\t<"+j+">" + cells.eq(i).text() + "</"+j+">\n";
                    xml += "\t<row>" + cells.eq(i).text() + "</row>\n";
                //}               
            }
            xml += "</rowset>\n";
        }
    });
    window.alert(xml);      
    }); 
  });
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPQK5/165/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a bit easier if you format your `table` to include header with `th` as you can see in the following code, because separating header text from other rows is going to make things a bit simpler.

Here's JS for that :

```
$("#idXmlData").click(function(){
    var xmlStart =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">";
    var xml = xmlStart;
    var xmlFirstRowSet = "<rowset><row name='";
    var thArray = new Array();
    $('th').each( function(index) {
        thArray[index] = $(this).html();
    });
    xmlFirstRowSet = xmlFirstRowSet + thArray[0] + "'>";
    var headerRowSet='';

    for(var i=1; i< thArray.length; i++) {
      headerRowSet =  headerRowSet + "<row>" + thArray[i] + "</row>";
    }

    headerRowSet = headerRowSet + "</rowset>";
    xmlFirstRowSet = xmlFirstRowSet + headerRowSet;
    var bodyRowSet ='';

    $(".mutliple tbody tr").each(function() {
        bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<rowset name='" + $(this).find('td').html() + "'>";
        $(this).find('td:not(:first-child)').each(function() {
           $td = $(this);
           var tdValue = $(this).html();
           var $th = $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index()).html();
           bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<" + $th + ">" + tdValue + "</" + $th + ">";  
        });
        bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "</rowset>";
    });

    xml = xmlStart + xmlFirstRowSet + bodyRowSet;
    console.log(xml);
    window.alert(xml);      
});
```

Here's a working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfc8zttu/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution!